# How to do a Go project workspace to work with dependencies tools and go tools?

Tags: vim, emacs, go, dependency-management

I have a project with packages inside:

- project package "root": `a/b/c` (eg github/b/c)
- in `a/b/c` we have a lot of packages (p1, p2 ...)
- project is managed according to [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) official recommendations. The local project path is: `$GOPATH/src/a/b/c`. Also all imports are "not relative".
- the project has *go get*-able dependencies

Now I want to use some dependency manager tool like [gom](https://github.com/mattn/gom) or [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep). Each of this tool creates an extra directory in repository and puts all vendor dependencies there. Also it plays with `GOPATH` and sets it to that vendor directory. Let's assume that the tool will put all vendors in `path_to_project/.vendor` - becoming a new `GOPATH`.

I want to use one of the go tools (`gofmt`, `gorename`, ...) being aware about packages in my projects and vendor directory. The problem is that if `GOPATH=path_to_project/.vendor` (*godep* does this) then tools are not aware about packages in my project.

One idea for this is to set a `GOPATH=path_to_project/.vendor:GOPATH` in a shell end editors. Or call every command with `gom exec` (gom sets a GOPATH in the above proposition)

**Is there any ready and automatic solution for this?**

Final goal is to bundle go project with specified dependencies versions (like git commits) and make tools + editors (vim/emacs) working with this tools.

Comment: I use godep and just update my GOPATH. `GOPATH=\`godep path\`:$GOPATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using godep, you can just prefix the go command with godep like this:

```
godep go build
```

or

```
godep go fmt
```

Comment: And the same for `gom`. One can execute any command which will require updated GOPATH by: `gom exec <your command> [args...]`